# value changes while reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, casting, reinterpret-cast

while converting an integer to float by using reinterpret_cast the content of memory changes.

For example,

```
   float fDest = 0;
  __int32 nTempDest = -4808638;

  fDest = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&nTempDest);
```

Hexadecimal representation for the variable value nTempest is '42 a0 b6 ff' but after reinterpret_cast the content of fDest is '42 a0 f6 ff'.

Can any one could give an answer why this third byte changed from b6 to f6.

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't change. There's no reason why it would.

Comment: need proof (printf %x) and architecture

Comment: @user1610015: The code is violating strict aliasing rules, the behavior is undefined. I get `-nan` when I tried it.

Comment: @user1610015: UB does not mandate that the program must produce erroneous output.

Comment: @JesseGood I get something like NAN too (-1.#QNAN), but what I meant is that the actual bits don't change.

Comment: @user1610015: That doesn't make sense to me. The IEEE standard specifies the bit representation for NaN, etc.

Comment: @JesseGoodI don't understand what doesn't make sense to you...

Comment: @AlokSave Saying that it's UB is not really useful information. UB simply means that it's not defined by the spec, but obviously it will have a specific behavior under each implementation. In this case, judging by the __int32 type, bijesh is probably using Visual C++ (or maybe Intel C++ since it is said to be source-compatible with VC++).

Comment: @user1610015 You are confusing undefined behaviour and unspecified behaviour. *The latter* has a specific, implementation-defined behaviour but this code exposes the former.

Comment: @KonradRudolph What's the difference?

Comment: @user1610015 *Unspecified* means that the standard does not impose a specific behaviour, but each implementation must define it and be consistent. For example, the size of `int` is unspecified, but each implementation must define and use a consistent size. On the other hand, *undefined* means that anything can happen, implementations don't need to care or be consistent with these cases.

Comment: @Gorpik OK, they don't "need" to care, but in this case they do. Using reinterpret_cast to interpret some memory as another type is a very common and well-defined under any well-known compiler.

Comment: @user1610015: No. The compiler can legally get the app to print out "Here be Dragons" and still be conforming when you invoke undefined behavior. The point is anything can and does happen especially when you start firing up the optimizations the invariants are broken and the optimizations tend to screw things up really badly.

Comment: @LokiAstari You start by saying "no" and then go on to say stuff that doesn't have anything to do with what I said. I only said using reinterpret_cast to interpret memory as a different type is common and well-defined with most compilers (actually this has more to do with processor architectures). This has nothing to do with standards conformance.

Comment: @user1610015: Then you need to re-read what I wrote.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Saying it is UB is useful information because it tells, *"No,You should not do this"*.Technically as per the standard *obvious* part of your statement may or may not be true.An implementation might show some specific behavior for the case. But since the behavior is non standard conforming,there is no binding compulsion on the implementation to provide the same behavior always.A good implementation will & should show some consistent behavior but it doesn't have to & if it doesn't you can't pin the blame on it. blame is all yours because you wrote a non standard conforming code.

Comment: @Alok Er, wrong recipient.

Answer (score 2):

In pure C++ this is in fact undefined behavior. Nevertheless there is an explanation for what you see.

I assume that the hexadecimal representations you give are from a bytewise view of memory. Obviously you are on a little endian architecture. So the 32-bit quantity we are starting from is 0xffb6a042, which is indeed the two's complement representation of -4808638.

As a IEC 60559 single-precision floating point number (also 32 bits) 0xffb6a042 is a negative, signaling NaN. NaNs in this representation have the form (in binary)

```
s1111111 1qxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx
```

Here s is the sign, the x are arbitrary and q=1 for a quiet NaN and q=0 for a signaling NaN.

Now you are using the signaling Nan in that you assign it to fDest. This would raise a floating point invalid exception if floating point signaling is active. By default such exceptions are simply ignored and signaling NaN values are 'quieted' when propagated on.

So: In assigning to fDest, the NaN is propagated and the implementation converts it to a quiet NaN by setting bit 22. This is the change you observe.

Answer (score 1):

Your code produces an **Undefined Behavior(UB)**.
`reinterpret_cast` only gives the guarantee that if you cast from one pointer type to another and cast it back to the original pointer type then you get the original data. Anything other than that produces UB<sup>[Note 1]</sup>

This is an UB because you cannot rely on the fact that:

```
sizeof(float) == sizeof(nTempDest)
```

This is not guaranteed to be `true` on all implementations, definitely not true for the ones which follow strict aliasing. And if the implementation doesn't what you get is Undefined Behavior.

---

<sup>[Note 1]</sup>*There are exceptions to this rule, if you need to rely on these corner rules, you are swimming in rough waters, So be absolutely sure of what you are doing.*

Comment: And why is this incorrect? Any technical reasons for downvote will help.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but it would be better if you mentioned one *pointer* type to another and back. However, I don't recall even that is unconditionally true.

Comment: I can't say for sure since I wasn't the down-voter, but I'd guess it's because that's not the only thing that gives defined behavior. Just for example: "When a prvalue v of type “pointer to T1” is converted to the type “pointer to cv T2”, the result is static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v)) if both T1 and T2 are standard-layout types (3.9) and the alignment requirements of T2 are no stricter than those of T1, or if either type is void."

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Yes, I just revisited the spec to check on *other* defined usages and found it at §5.2.10.7. I agree my answer mentioned the general guideline for usage of `reinterpret_cast`. Yes there are corner cases but this case is definitely an UB.

Comment: @AlokSave: yes, this one is, but: "Anything other than that produces UB" is simply false.

Comment: -1: For your "Note1": that is not footnote-worthy material. There is no reason not to rely upon such behavior if it's protected by the standard.

Comment: @NicolBolas: That note is not for standard pundits it's for regular users who might not understand the standerdese as well as a standard purist does.

Comment: @AlokSave: "Regular users" absolutely *should* know about standard layout rules. Regular users should know that these kinds of `reinterpret_cast`s are perfectly legal. Talking down to your audience helps nobody.